# Adding to a local grid datasource created with Kendo for ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I've found an odd interaction with the Kendo for ASP.Net Grid control when adding records.

You can't create a true local datasource using the C# bindings - instead the published advice is to use an Ajax datasource with ServerOperations set to false.

I can programmatically add records to this grid without a problem and paging works fine when using the numbered part of the pager. However when clicking on any of the navigation buttons on the page (first, previous, next, last) the changes appear to be lost and the grid reverts to showing the original data. However if I set the page using javascript it will then show the correct data.

This problem doesn't occur if I replace the datasource on the C# grid with one I have created via javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about your code for "adding records".
In my project(ASP MVC 4 + kendo Wraper). I custom datasource by this way:

//Get DataSource object

```
var dataSource = $('#myGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource;
//Pusth new data to Data-Source
dataSource.transport.options.data.Data.push(objNewItem);
//Re-counting number of records
dataSource.transport.options.data.Total = dataSource.transport.options.data.Data.length;
```

This code have been working great up to now.
You can change page, use "first, previous, next, last" function  or you can reload datasource/go to specific page number like this:

```
dataSource.read();
dataSource.page(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - but I'm still getting the same problem. It adds the data but then fails when I hit "next page".
Which version of the MVC library are you using?

Comment: @Chris I'm using ASP MVC 4, C# for code-behind and use Razor for view engine. So, what is the error did you get ?

Comment: Sorry I meant which version of the libraries are you using. I'm getting the error with 2012.3.1114

Comment: Oops, I use the older one, 2012.2.710 . Maybe in your version Kendo had changed Datasource structure.

Comment: @Chris Hey Chris , I have just testd on the last version of Kendoui (in this Demo : http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html)
I have to use this instead:
dataSource.transport.options.data.push(objNewItem); (only this code for push data )